# Stuck in New Message email client in iOS App

Tags: ios, email

I am trying to implement MessageUI and MFMailComposeViewController in order to send emails in my app. It all seems to work fine, except I can't actually leave the mail client once I've started the process. If I hit send, it sends, and then does nothing else (does not return to app). If I hit cancel, it does not delete draft and kit (or return to app again).

```
import UIKit
import MessageUI

class ContactFormViewController: UITableViewController, MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate {

...

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    switch indexPath.item{
        case 0:
            followOnEmail()
        default:
            break
    }
}

private func mailComposeController(controller: MFMailComposeViewController, didFinishWithResult result: MFMailComposeResult, error: NSError?) {
    controller.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func followOnEmail(){
    if !MFMailComposeViewController.canSendMail(){
        print("Mail services are not available")
        return
    }

    let composeVC = MFMailComposeViewController()
    composeVC.mailComposeDelegate = self

    // Configure the fields of the interface.
    composeVC.setToRecipients(["info@cegainnovations.com"])
    composeVC.setSubject("")
    composeVC.setMessageBody("Please enter your message below.", isHTML: false)

    if MFMailComposeViewController.canSendMail(){
        // Present the view controller modally.
        self.present(composeVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    else{
        self.showSendMailErrorAlert()
    }
}

...

func showSendMailErrorAlert(){
    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Could Not Send Email", message: "Your device could not send email. Please check e-mail configuration and try again.", preferredStyle: .alert)
    let defaultAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Close", style: .default, handler: nil)
    alertController.addAction(defaultAction)
    present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swift 3 changed the API slightly.
change

```
private func mailComposeController(controller: MFMailComposeViewController, didFinishWithResult result: MFMailComposeResult, error: NSError?) {
```

to

```
func mailComposeController(_ controller: MFMailComposeViewController, didFinishWith result: MFMailComposeResult, error: Error?) {
```